# Digital root of prime numbers,why the digital root of this two prime are the same?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

A is prime greater than 5,  B  is  A*(A-1)+1,if B is prime,

then digital root of A and B must the same.(OEIS A065508)

Sample: 13*(13-1)+1 = 157 
13 and 157 are prime and have same digital root 4

Comment: What can you say about the remainder of $A$ modulo $9$ from the condition that $A$ and $B$ are primes?

Comment: Thanks,modulo 9 is more precisely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**: consider mod 9. What happens in each of these cases?

Use the fact that B us prime, and in particular not a multiple of 3

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases: $A=3k-1$ and $A=3k+1$.
Expand $A*(A-1)+1$ in both these cases.
$B=9k^2-9k+3$ or $B=9k^2+3k+1$